# Testing a component that uses React.useEffect using enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, enzyme, react-testing-library

Let's say I have this functional React component.

```
const SomeComponent = ({ onShow }) => {
  React.useEffect(onShow, []);
  return <div />;
};
```

Now I want to unit test that `SomeComponent` calls onShow the first time it is rendered.

Is that possible using `enzyme`?

---

I have tried implementing two very similar tests, the difference being that the first is using enzyme, the other one using react-testing-library.

The test that uses react-testing-library passes, but the enzyme test fails, even though they test the same code.

Example:

```
import * as reactTestingLibrary from "react-testing-library";
import * as React from "react";
import * as enzyme from "enzyme";

const SomeComponent = ({ onShow }) => {
  React.useEffect(onShow, []);
  return <div />;
};

describe("Testing useEffect with enzyme", () => {
  it("calls the side effect", async () => {
    const aFn = jest.fn();
    enzyme.mount(<SomeComponent onShow={aFn} />);
    expect(aFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // this test fails
  });
});

describe("Testing useEffect with react-testing-library", () => {
  it("calls the side effect", async () => {
    const aFn = jest.fn();
    reactTestingLibrary.render(<SomeComponent onShow={aFn} />);
    expect(aFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // this test passes
  });
});
```

Is there a way to make enzyme execute the hook and pass the test?

Comment: Can you update your libraries. For me both of the tests are working --> `"react": "^16.8.6"`, `"enzyme": "^3.9.0"`, `"react-testing-library": "^7.0.0", `, `"react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",`

Comment: @tarzenchugh I had the latest versions in your list but I had missed to upgrade the enzyme adapter. Upgrading enzyme-adapter-react-16 to 1.12.1 fixed my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your welcome; Welcome to stack overflow :)

Comment: please create answer and mark it as a solution; I believe there may be other people running into that and having solution in comments makes that harder to realize

Comment: toHaveBeenCalled is a horrible test to begin with.  You're not testing any kind of behavior our output and you're reaching into the details of your component

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to test components that uses hooks, using enzyme.

Upgrading enzyme-adapter-react-16 to latest version (1.12.1) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i just upgraded my enzyme-adapter-react-16 to v1.12.1, that sorted it out for me.